# Ping an express + sequelize server with chai-http

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, chai-http

I'm having issue on setting up tests with Express and Sequelize. I'm using Mocha + Chai for tests. I'm just trying to ping for now.

Code of server.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const db = require('./config/db');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const PORT = 8000;

//Use body parser for express
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const sequelize = new Sequelize(db.database, db.user, db.password, {
  host: db.host,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  operatorsAliases: false,
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    //Import Routes
    require('./app/routes/')(router, sequelize);

    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.json('Welcome to Dickson Connect API :)');
    })

    //Make express Listen
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log('We are live on ' + PORT);
    })

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

//For chai testing
module.exports = app;
```

The server is working.

and the test.js :

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaitHttp = require('chai-http');
const server = require('../../server');

const should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaitHttp);

describe('/GET', () => {

  it('should display a welcome message', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
    .get('/')
    .then( (res) => {

      res.should.have.status(200);

      done();
    })
    .catch( err => {
      throw err;
    })
  })
})
```

I believe at least part of the problem is that my server is returning a sequelize instance containing the express app which might not be the usual case. Though, the sequelize is just a promise which I'm waiting for in my chai test, using `then` instead of `end`.

this is the error I'm getting :

> /GET
>   (node:35436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: expected { Object (domain, _events, ...) } to have status code 200 but got 404
>       at chai.request.get.then (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api_dickson/app/routes/index.test.js:16:23)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
>   (node:35436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:35436) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>   Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
>   We are live on 8000
>       1) should display a welcome message
>
> 0 passing (2s)
>    1 failing
>
> 1) /GET
>          should display a welcome message:
>        Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

No need to tell you I'm starting with those testing stuff (finally...) and therefore, I'm not getting everything yet. Thanks a lot for your help !

PAM

Comment: In this line: require('./app/routes/')(router, sequelize);  what is the purpose of sequelize?

Comment: Hi . Purpose of this line is to pass the DB connection (sequelize) to others routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` you have comes from your test, try to do `.then(done, done)` after the assertion block instead of calling `done()` and adding a `.catch` block.

```
it('should display a welcome message', (done) => {
  chai.request(server).get('/')
  .then((res) => {
    res.should.have.status(200);
  })
  .then(done, done);
})
```

Also, about the 404, it's because you set your routes inside the `sequelize.authenticate()` promise, so when you export your app for the tests, the routes aren't set up. Just move the routes definition (and add a `app.use('/', router);` statement aswell, else your routes won't be used) above the Promise.

```
(...)
const sequelize = new Sequelize(...);

require('./app/routes/')(router, sequelize);
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json('Welcome to Dickson Connect API :)');
})

app.use("/", router);

sequelize
.authenticate()
.then(() => {
  //Make express Listen
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('We are live on ' + PORT);
  })
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});

//For chai testing
module.exports = app;
```